# How to programmatically search archive of CNN headlines?

Tags: api

Is screen scraping the best way to accomplish this?

I can't find a CNN API, but are there third-party APIs that allow you to access archives of CNN headlines, perhaps indirectly through past RSS feeds?

I only need to access the last 60 days worth of headlines.

Thanks!

Comment: Screen scraping and using the data as your own is probably not a good idea. If there are no APIs, it's probably for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CNN introduced developer API keys, but you have to apply for them. I was able to apply for one for a project. You are limited in the amount of queries you can do. 
[Here's the link](https://developer.cnn.com/page)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the RSS feeds here: http://www.cnn.com/services/rss/  You may also want to look at using feedburner.  For programmatically scraping the CNN RSS feeds, take a look at library like Python pattern.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to be only a subset of the articles ... know how we can get a comprehensive list?